# ansible-vault encrypt credentials

Tags: ansible

I have an inventory file with one host:

> 10.1.32.123 ansible_ssh_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant

My `yaml` file:

```
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  gather_facts: yes
  serial: 20

  roles:
```

It's not the `yaml` file I wish to password protect but my inventory file, since it contains user credentials. It's although not possible, as when I run the playbook, the content in the inventory file doesn't decrypt. It does if I have the `yaml` file encrypted.

```
ansible-playbook inventory site.yml --ask-vault-pass
```

1. Is there a way to add the credentials: `ansible_ssh_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant` to the `yaml` file and just keep the IP in the inventory file.

**DOCS:**

[VAULT](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_vault.html)

Comment: Did you create your inventory file with ansible-vault? Like `ansible-vault create foo.yml`? What error do you see when you say 'file doesnt decrypt' ?

Comment: It's not the `foo.yml` file I wish to encrypt, but the inventory file, that keeps the IP's and credentials of the VM's. `foo.yml` is possible to password protect. The error I get is decryption errors. For Ansible the inventory is still encrypted when running it, with stated password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can encrypt the hosts file. A much better approach would be to have any sensitive information like credentials stored in a secondary vars file that's encrypted with ansible-vault and then just include that file in your playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  gather_facts: yes
  vars_files:
    - /path/to/encrypted/vars.yml
```

Your `inventory` file contains a host:

```
10.1.1.2
```

Your `vars/vars.yml` will store your credentials:

```
ansible_ssh_user: vagrant
ansible_ssh_password: vagrant
```

To use more than one host you can add groups in the inventory file. The hosts that are in the specific group are sharing the same credentials:

```
[group1]
10.1.1.2
10.1.1.3

[group2]
10.1.1.4
10.1.1.5
```

Your playbook will now have two hosts sections:

```
- hosts: group1
  vars_files:
    - vars/group1.yml

- hosts: group2
  vars_files:
    - vars/group2.yml
```

The `group1.yml` and `group2.yml` files must share the same password.

Comment: Should `vars.yml` have the IP and credentials of the hosts? What info would the (hosts) inventory file contain now? And what would my inventory file contain? I got: `vars.yml must be stored as a dictionary/hash` when I ran `ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml --ask-vault-pass`

Comment: You can put as much or as little in the inventory file & the vars file(s) as you determine is necessary.  Personally I think it's better to keep host-related things like IP addresses, etc. in the inventory file, non-sensitive variables in one vars file and sensitive variables in a second encrypted vars file.  With a little searching you can find lots of examples, like [this one](http://willthames.github.io/2014/04/02/modelling-credentials-configuration-in-ansible.html).

Comment: I extended your answer with description on how to set it up.

Comment: `ansible_ssh_password` was not working for me, had to replace it with `ansible_ssh_pass`.